# Interfacing NAND flash with USBMSD

Tags: memory, flash, usb-device

I'm trying to read files from a NAND flash ([K9LAG08U0M](http://www.datasheet.co.kr/datasheet-html/K/9/L/K9LAG08U0M_SamsungElectronics.pdf.html)) that I took off an old MP3 player, so far I've been able to read the NAND contents successfully by interfacing it to my PC as a USBMSD (Mass Storage Device) using an ARM microcontroller.

The problem is when I connect it, I get an "unknown partition table" error, looking closer the first page it doesn't seem have a valid MBR, after some searching I was able to locate the MBR at offset 0x7e800 (page number 253), this is what I get when using *file(1)* on that block (the MP3 was formated with FAT32)

> x86 boot sector, code offset 0x58, OEM-ID "ALiOS1.0",
>   sectors/cluster 2, reserved sectors 34, Media descriptor 0xf8, heads
>   255, sectors 248448 (volumes > 32 MB) , FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 963,
>   serial number 0x30a3239e, unlabeled

My question is, why isn't the MBR stored on the first page ? does this mean that the controller remapped the first block to another one ? if so, is there a way for me to figure out how bad blocks are managed (without the original controller) so I can do the same mapping in my code to read the filesystem ?

Thanks.

PS: I tried checking for bad blocks to see if block 0 is bad, according to the datasheet an initial bad block is identified by a non-FFh byte stored in the spare area of the last page in the block, but when I tried that almost 80% of the blocks show as bad blocks and the first block is not one of them, does this sound like a reasonable ratio to you ? or am I doing something wrong when checking for bad blocks ?

Some info about the flash:

8192 blocks

128 page per block

2K pages + 64 bytes spare area.

Comment: I am trying to follow your question. You say "2K pages+ 16 bytes spare area". Is this correct? On the datasheet you linked it says "2K + 64 bytes" on page 9.

Comment: @ArikRaffaelFunke yes sorry that was a typo